# how to remove duplicate values after fetching values from the database

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code.

```
$sql   = "select id from user";
$users = mysql_query($sql);
while($urow = mysql_fetch_row($users))
{ 
  echo urow[0];
}
```

when i run this code i am getting values 2,2,33,6,6.I want to remove the duplicated values from this.i need values 2,33,6 as output.

Comment: The `id` column should not have duplicated values. You need to fix this.

Comment: Agree with @bsdnoobz. "id" cannot have duplicate values in the first place if you seek it to serve a unique identifier

Comment: id is another field,its not a unique key

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DISTINCT` in your query to get unique values:

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT(id) from user"
```

http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can even try `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM user`, which will let you stop duplicates at SQL level itself.

Comment: @coolboy: Then just code it, it's trivial and has been already asked before. Also your question is not well-formulated if that was not clear from begin on.

Answer (score 0):

Get your result as a array and then use the [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function

> array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array